# cannot send messages to another instance of android phone after following the tutorial guestbook tutorial for mobile backend starter

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to the mobile backend starter.  I followed the tutorial on the mobile backend starter page.  After following the whole tutorial including the authentication part, i deployed the same instance of my code on 2 different android phones. When i send messages from one instance of android phone, i doesnt show on the other instance of the android phone until i restart the app on the other instance. Also i have set the setscope value to scope.Future_AND_Past and not Scope.PAST.
I was wondering what should be done to make sure that the chat service works. At the moment messages get pushed to the server but the app is not able to do continuous query.
Please help, I am really stuck!!

Comment: Can you please mention which tutorial did you followed?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend.

I followed the whole tutorial upto enable authentication[https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/enable_auth].  I am having problems with push messaging(continuous query) part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to PUSH messaging not being properly configured.  There's not a lot of detail in this question as to what has been tried, so as an answer I can only suggest common "gotchas" in fixing this.. Indeed it is fiddly to get going...

1) Did you enable Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) in the Google Developer Console?  Under APIs&Auth Tab the API for GCM needs to be switched green.

2) Have you set up Consts.java to contain the PROJECT_ID typically in form "word-word-etc", the PROJECT_NUMBER which is numeric.  You also need to set the WEB_CLIENT_ID to be of format nnnnn-kkkkkkk.apps.googleusercontent.com where nnnnn is your PROJECT_NUMBER and kkkkk is some secret key.  If you don't have a WEB_CLIENT_ID yet then you have to make one in APIs&Auth/Credentials in the Google Dev Console.. click on Create Client ID and make the type "Web Application".  You should get a key generated that looks likes this in the console:

> Client ID  nnnnnnnn-kkkkkkkkk.apps.googleusercontent.com
>
> Email address  nnnnnnnn-kkkkkkkkkkkkk@developer.gserviceaccount.com
>
> Client secret  ljflksjdflksjdflksjdf
>
> Redirect URIs  https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/oauth2callback
>
> Javascript Origins https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com

where PROJECT_ID is your project ID i.e. word-word-etc

3) Did you enable Push messaging on the server side in the control panel for your app? You can do it by visiting your backend's config page at link below (visiting this page will verify also you deployed the server side successfully)

https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/admin/configure.jsp

On that config page you need to

3a) check the "enable google cloud messaging" radio button

3b) set the google cloud messaging key field to a SERVER API key.. you can generate this in Google Dev Console under the APIs & Auth / Credentials tab... you need the key to be of "server" type and I believe it is best to allow any IP.

Finally on that config page there is a "broadcast message" section which will send out a PUSH GCM to your device - try typing a message and hitting broadcast, then watch the LogCat on your device you should see some Log.I class messages appearing.  Good luck.

Comment: i followed the whole tutorial all over again.  But still the same issue.  Do you think this is a bug in mobile backend starter?

Comment: No, I don't.. I think there may be some bugs in MBS but with regard to push notifications and this demo I think the tutorials e.g. at Google IO 2013 show it working with push and I have also got this feature working with MBS.